# Creating a structuring element IN AFORGE.NET

Tags: c#, image-processing, aforge

I need to create a structuring element of size 4x13. What i understood was the structuring element can be something like 3x3, 5x5 or 13x13 for my case. if I am to create 4x13 should it be like 13x13 structuring element should i fill the 4x13 area of it with "1" and the rest zeros? because Aforge.Net would not let me use a 4x13 directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to create a method that would automatically fill the indexes for me